# QR decomposition of MATLAB equivalent in Armadillo (C++)?

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, armadillo

I am  trying to port a MATLAB code into C++. And using the Armadillo package.

Matlab code:

[Q,R,P] = qr(A);
Where Q is lxl, R is lxn and P nxn(permutation matrix)

But in C++ (Using Armadillo package I have only )
qr(Q,R,A)

I am missing the 'P' matrix in the armadillo implementation. Any idea how to have the equivalent statement in the C++ or how to get the Q,R and P matrix in C++ (equivalent of the MATLAB)

Comment: From the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#qr), it seems like there is no implicit permutation of the matrix. Why do you need the Permutation matrix?

Comment: For the optimization purposes.